# Responsive Equal Height elements in rows

Tags: javascript

I came across this page which talks about how to assign equal heights to all items on a row by row basis.  It's exactly what I need but I can't seem to get it working and am just unsure where it is going wrong.  I have converted it into vanilla JS so it may be something to do with that.  As for why I need to use JS to achieve this.  I have some pretty complicated nesting going on and CSS Grid is fine for my main layout but the nested items break this, therefore the JS requirement.  Please could someone see if they can see anything wrong with the code?

```
var currentTallest = 0,
    currentRowStart = 0,
    rowDivs = new Array()

function setHeight(el, newHeight) {
  // set the height to something new, but remember the original height in case things change
  let height = getOriginalHeight(el)

  el.setAttribute("data-originalHeight", height)
  el.style.height = newHeight + 'px'
}

function getOriginalHeight(el) {
  // if the height has changed, send the originalHeight
  if (el.getAttribute("data-originalHeight") == undefined) {
    return el.offsetHeight
  } else {
    return el.getAttribute("data-originalHeight")
  }
}

function columnConform() {
  // find the tallest DIV in the row, and set the heights of all of the DIVs to match it.
  document.querySelectorAll('.my-grid .car').forEach(el => {
    let topPosition = getOffsetTop(el)
    console.log(rowDivs)

    if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {
      // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
      for(let currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) setHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest)

      // set the variables for the new row
      rowDivs.length = 0 // empty the array
      currentRowStart = topPosition
      currentTallest = getOriginalHeight(el)
      rowDivs.push(el)
    } else {
      // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
      rowDivs.push(el)
      currentTallest = (currentTallest < getOriginalHeight(el)) ? (getOriginalHeight(el)) : (currentTallest)
    }
  })

  // do the last row
  for (let currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
    setHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS this code acts on, and how the functions are called. A [mre], in other words. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a running example here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: why not just use flexbox

Comment: @DCR I can't due to some of the items i need equalising in height are nested in a parent element therefore Grid or Flexbox won't work.

Comment: @heretic-monkey I will try to get an example up shortly.

Comment: can you provide a sketch of what you want it to look like?

Comment: I will work on a demo but i'm having trouble building a simple reproduceable version as my codepen appears to work fine.  I'll continue debugging and come back here if I continue to experience trouble.